# Calculate Size of documents in a Directory using CMD

Tags: file, cmd, count, directory, size

I have one directory Named documents, which have .doc,.xlsx,.pdf,.htm etc files and other directories.

I want to calculate the size of any type of document in this directory using CMD.

For example : i need to count number of .html documents and their total size.

Dir command is showing total numbers of files and their size.

Comment: Made any attempt or just awaiting code??

Answer (score 0):

Get all available extensions in a first `for` loop.
Use a second `for` loop to iterate through every found extension.
Get number of files and cumulated size with a third (nested) `for`loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal &REM enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
  set "ext_%%~xa=*%%~xa"
)
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set ext_') do (
  for /f "tokens=1,3" %%b in ('dir /-c %%a^|findstr /e "Bytes"') do echo %%a:  Files:%%b  Size: %%c
)
```

Note: you might have to adapt "tokens=1,3" and the `"Bytes"` string to your language. On my (German) windows, the summary of `dir /a-d /-c` looks like:

```
          15 Datei(en),         42291 Bytes               <<< this is the needed line
           0 Verzeichnis(se), 358679015424 Bytes frei
```

(note: `dir /-c` removes the "Thousands-Separator", which is a dot `.` in some languages and a comma `,` in others)

Comment: What about looking for the next-to-last line of the output of `dir`, so you would no longer depend on the `Bytes` string? By the way, you are describing `dir /a-d /-c`, but you are using `dir /-c` in your code...

Comment: @aschipfl like `for /f "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('dir /a-d /-c * ^|findstr /bc:"      "') do if not defined x set x=%%a %%b` and 
`echo %x%`? Definitively a step into the right direction. Still the question: is it always token 1 and 3?

Comment: Not quite, this would store the first line into `x`; I was thinking of something like `set "x=" & set "y="`, then `for /f "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('dir /a-d /-c * ^|findstr /bc:" "') do set "y=!x!" & set "x=%%a %%b"` and `echo/%y%` (actually delayed expansion needs to be toggled properly to be safe). Unfortunately I cannot answer the tokens question either; I don't think Microsoft can... ;-)

Comment: @aschipfl: "Comment mis-formatting": it`s `findstr /bc: "<six spaces>" and works fine. And you are correct about delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is two examples, *you should only need to edit/confirm the file path on line 2*:

The first uses `Dir` and tries to locate the required line according to your question:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcDir=%UserProfile%\Documents"

If "%~1"=="" (Set "_=%SrcDir%\*.*") Else Set "_=%SrcDir%\*.%~1"
If Not Exist "%_%" (Echo %_%    No matches&GoTo EndIt)

Set "$="
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('Dir/D/-C "%_%"^|FindStr/BC:"  "'
) Do If Not Defined $ Set "$=%_%    %%A"
Echo(%$%

:EndIt
Timeout -1
```

The second uses PowerShell, which gives you more control over for instance the file size units, *(I've used kB)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcDir=%UserProfile%\Documents"

If "%~1"=="" (Set "_=%SrcDir%\*.*") Else Set "_=%SrcDir%\*.%~1"
If Not Exist "%_%" (Echo %_%    No matches&GoTo EndIt)

Powershell -C "$n=(GCI '%_%'|Measure).Count;"^
 "$s=[Math]::Round((GCI '%_%'|Measure -S Length).Sum/1kB,2);"^
 "Write-Host '%_%   ' $n 'file(s) totalling' $s'kB'"

:EndIt
Timeout -1
```

Either:

- double click it - to total `all` files in `%SrcDir%`

Or:

- via command line:

  - `scriptName.cmd` - to total `all` files in `%SrcDir%`
  - `scriptName.cmd xlsx` - to total `.xlsx` files in `%SrcDir%`

Note: On lines `5` and `9` the whitespace immediately following `%_%` is a single <kbd>Tab</kbd>